# How to finance necessary repairs to our home in order to sell it?

Tags: refinance

We are planning on downsizing due to financial and health issueswithin 12 - 18 months and need to do some repairs in order to get a fair price.  The house is peeling and needs exterioir painting as well as painting due to cracks and stains inside. Some of the appliances are also on their last legs. We own close to 70% of the home's equity (est. $400K) and we estimate only needing roughly $25,000 is needed but during my research I've learned that some HELOC lenders won't accept fast paybacks or selling your home.  What are our best options for funding the repairs with the lowest interest rates?

Comment: Something to keep in mind (you don't need to answer here): Have you confirmed with a realtor that all of the repairs are necessary to get a fair price? Will the proposed repairs/refurbishments have enough of an ROI to bother doing?

Comment: Seconding @BobbyScon. Most renovations do not pay for themselves in sale price. The best time to fix things up is when you'll be living in the house to enjoy the improvement. First impression does matter, so if your paint's really that far gone this seems worth considering. But the potential buyer may not agree with your appliance choices.

Comment: My parents-in-law renovated my grandparents-in-law's house to sell it, on the recommendation of their real estate agent. They got lots of bids but the winner was a flipper who re-renovated it including the appliances and paint. So the money and time they spent on the renovations was almost completely wasted. That said, generally speaking, deferred maintenance and paint are usually worth doing to prepare for a sale.

Answer (score 3):

A typical HELOC will have about $300 in fees to open it. From there, it's up to you how much or how long to use it.

I'd shop around to find the bank that offers the right product for you.